# JSON API response from controller to View

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to get passing JSON response from controller to view but the JSON array is changed.
How to pass the JSON array as i get from the Api.

Controller code:

```
$client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', env('API_URL').'/profile_question', [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
            ],
        ])->getBody();

        $response = json_decode($response);

        return view('account/incomplete_profile', compact(['response']));
```

dd result in controller:

```
{#273 ▼
  +"swingstatus": array:3 [▶]
  +"searchingfor": []
  +"language": []
  +"headline": []
  +"description": []
  +"lookingfor": []
  +"birthday": []
  +"eyes": []
  +"haircolor": []
  +"height": []
  +"weight": []
  +"bodytype": []
  +"raceethnics": []
  +"smokes": []
  +"piercings": []
  +"tattoos": []
  +"sexuality": []
  +"hasexperience": []
  +"looksareimportant": []
  +"integlligence": []
  +"hairlength": []
  +"bodyhair": []
  +"comfortlevel": []
  +"whatdoyoulike": []
  +"fetish": []
}
```

dd from view:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#284 ▶}
  1 => {#289 ▶}
  2 => {#287 ▶}
]
```

Can anyone help me to get the Api output inside mine view without changing?

Answer (score 0):

seems you are mixing naming

```
$response = json_decode($response);
```

try this

```
$r = json_decode($response);
```

and because you are getting data from api than try to collect data into laravel collection

```
$collections = collect($r);
```

now good to go in view

```
return view('account.incomplete_profile', compact('collections'));
```

hope this helps

Comment: please greentick my answer